# Change eth3 to eth1 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I'm connecting a router to my laptop in Ubuntu 12.04, and for some reasons it shows it as **eth3**. My program is hardcoded asa **eth1**. I was wondering how I can change it to eth1.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on 12.04. I reckon it would on subsequent releases. First find out your interface name, to make sure there isn't eth1 already in use somewhere. To do so type this into a terminal:

```
ifconfig -a
```

You will definitely have one loopback interface called 'lo' with the IPaddress 127.0.0.1. This is not the interface you are looking for. Look at the other one that has a name like eth1 to see if it exists. If it does, then.. well Don't do anything more. If there isn't a eth1, then you're free to change the eth3 to eth1.

As root edit the file /etc/network/interfaces, look for a line that looks something like this:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 

auto eth3 
iface eth3 inet dhcp
```

Rename the eth3 to eth1. And restart networking.

Comment: Ummm, good. I know about "interfacs" file. But unfortunately there is nothing other than the first interface, lo one.